# Disable dhtmlx editor (read-only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx editor and I want to disable editing once checkbox is checked. I went through the documentation but I did not find any API to disable editing. Is there any way I can disable editing.

Answer (score 0):

An iframe will be generated when dhtmlx editor is initialized. Within this iframe the body tag  contents is actually the html content what would appear. This body tag has an attribute `contenteditable = "true"`. So what I needed was just to set this attribute to "false" to disable editing. I did this as below :


`$('iframe').contents().find('body').attr('contenteditable', "false");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of dhtmlx you're using but in the latest version the editor component has a function to set it to readonly editor.setReadonly(boolean); where boolean is true or false.
I found this by playing in the firebug console to see al the function related to that object since in the DHTMLX official documentation is not stated.

```
var editor = new dhtmlXEditor("editorObj");
editor.setReadonly(true)
```